# Find the maximum value from JSON data in Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing

I am very new to programming in Scala. I am writing a test program to get maximum value from JSON data. I have following code:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.parsing.json._

object jsonParsing{

//Id int `json:"id"`
//Price int `json:"price"`

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val file_name = "jsonData.txt"

    val json_string = scala.io.Source.fromFile("jsonData.txt").getLines.mkString

    val json_arr = json_string.split(",")

    json_arr.foreach {println}  

    }
}
```

The json_arr.foreach {println} prints following data:

```
[{ "id":1
"price":4629}
 { "id":2
"price":7126}
 { "id":3
"price":8862}
 { "id":4
"price":8999}
 { "id":5
"price":1095}]
```

I am stuck at the part of figuring out how to find the maximum price from such JSON data? That is, in this case the output should be '8999'.

Comment: Have a look at [playJson](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson) or other Json parsing libraries.

Comment: @maasg Thanks. Play JSON seems helpful.

Comment: @maasg Is there any alternate way? Where I do not need any extra libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this below:

```
    package com.x.x.integration.commons

import collection.immutable.IndexedSeq
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser

case class wrapperObject(val json_string: Array[MyJsonObject])
case class MyJsonObject(val id:Int ,val price:Int)

object Demo {

    val gson = new Gson()
    def main(args: Array[String])={
        val json_string = scala.io.Source.fromFile("jsonData.txt").getLines.mkString
        //val json_string= """{"json_string":[{"id":1,"price":4629},{"id":2,"price":7126},{"id":3,"price":8862},{"id":4,"price":8999},{"id":5,"price":1095}]}"""
        val jsonStringAsObject= new JsonParser().parse(json_string).getAsJsonObject
        val objectThatYouCanPlayWith:wrapperObject = gson.fromJson(jsonStringAsObject, classOf[wrapperObject])
        var maxPrice:Int = 0
        for(i <- objectThatYouCanPlayWith.json_string if i.price>maxPrice) 
        {
            maxPrice=  i.price
        }
        println(maxPrice)
    }
}
```

check if it helps you

Comment: I tried to run the code. But there seems to be some problem with case class MyJsonObject{val id ,val price}

Comment: Sorry Buddy.. unfortunately i dint compile and pasted .. You can take the below code and try once,its working fine.You gotta make jars ready for gson and json api using maven dependency information below:

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>



and run below code,let me for any issues:

Comment: @ A srinivas: The code works, but you have inserted hard coded values for the string. That is not very efficient. I need that to work. So I can mark your answer as correct and vote it up.

Comment: I just edited the code,uncommented the above line and commented the hardcode string.it should work fine now ,having said that your json should be valid one in your file.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend to use [Json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) or playJson.

But you could do without any libraries as such.

```
val json = """[{"id":1,"price":100},{"id":2, "price": 200}]"""
val priceRegex = """"price"\s*:\s*(\d+)""".r

val maxPrice = priceRegex.findAllIn(json).map({
  case priceRegex(price) => price.toInt
}).max
println(maxPrice) // print 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Play JSON is handy, you could use Regex as well.

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.matching.Regex._

val jsonString = Source
    .fromFile("jsonData.txt")
    .getLines.mkString.split(",")

var maxPrice = 0
jsonString.foreach(each => {
   val price: Option[Match] = ("\"price\":(\\d+)").r.findFirstMatchIn(each)
   if (price.isDefined) {
      maxPrice = Math.max(maxPrice, price.get.group(1).toInt)
   }
})
```

Comment: This solution works and is good. However, I would have liked to do it with Play JSON or some other JSON parsing.

Comment: @hshantanu Absolutely! :)