# Not a JSON Object Exception in Scala

Tags: java, json, scala, parsing

With reference to answer in following post: [Find the maximum value from JSON data in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964648/find-the-maximum-value-from-json-data-in-scala)

I am very new to programming in Scala, and as one solution states in the mentioned post, I am testing following code:

```
import collection.immutable.IndexedSeq
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonParser

case class wrapperObject(val json_string: Array[MyJsonObject])
case class MyJsonObject(val id:Int ,val price:Int)

object Demo {

    val gson = new Gson()
    def main(args: Array[String])={
    val json_string = scala.io.Source.fromFile("jsonData.txt").getLines.mkString
    //val json_string= """{"json_string":[{"id":1,"price":4629},{"id":2,"price":7126},{"id":3,"price":8862},{"id":4,"price":8999},{"id":5,"price":1095}]}"""
    val jsonStringAsObject= new JsonParser().parse(json_string).getAsJsonObject
    val objectThatYouCanPlayWith:wrapperObject = gson.fromJson(jsonStringAsObject, classOf[wrapperObject])
    var maxPrice:Int = 0
    for(i <- objectThatYouCanPlayWith.json_string if i.price>maxPrice) 
    {
        maxPrice=  i.price
    }
    println(maxPrice)
}
}
```

I am getting following error at line 15. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object:

The contents of the JSON file are as follows:

```
[{ "id":978,"price":2513},
{ "id":979,"price":8942},
{ "id":980,"price":1268},
{ "id":981,"price":5452},
{ "id":982,"price":5585},
{ "id":983,"price":9542}]
```

Not sure as to why this error is appearing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your file does not contain a valid json. Please share the contents of jsonData.txt, but I would just search online for a json formatter that will highlight your issue for you.

Comment: Edited the question with contents of the JSON file. I have searched and tried using GSON.

Comment: I think your code may have worked if you had used `.getAsJsonArray` instead of `.getAsJsonObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file is not valid JSON format. As per the logic you implemented with `wrapperObject`, your file should look like this:

```
{
    "json_string": [
        { "id":978,"price":2513},
        { "id":979,"price":8942},
        { "id":980,"price":1268},
        { "id":981,"price":5452},
        { "id":982,"price":5585},
        { "id":983,"price":9542}
    ]
}
```

which will then give the output `9542`. Note that your commented out version of `json_string` is actually valid and the output would be `8999`.

JSON format is an attribute-value pair, but your file only has value - which is `Array[MyJsonObject]`. As per your `wrapperObject` case class, `json_string` is the attribute, and it's needed for `Gson` to parse the data into an object of type `wrapperObject`.